# Creating 3-D objects on Autocad/Revit and transferring it to Python

Tags: python, autocad, revit

I am curious if there are any ways in which I can design a model and transfer it into python.
As an example, if I was creating a game on python, and wanted to add a 3D house created in Autocad/Revit, is there any way to add that to my python game?
or are there any similar program which allows this sort of thing?

cheers